# InstallShield partially removes program after cancelling its removal

Tags: installshield, installscript, installscript-msi

I've got an Installscript MSI project that's behaving a bit oddly.

Following a successful installation, if I launch the installation file again, I get a pop-up with a question:

"Do you want to completely remove the selected application and all of its features?"

This, of course, is the expected behaviour.

If I select "No", the "InstallShield Wizard Completed" dialog is displayed, and it notifies me that "The wizard was interrupted before [the application] could be completely installed."

Again, this is all within expected behaviour.

The unexpected bit is that after closing this dialog, the application is partially removed from my machine. The installed files and registry keys are still present, but it no longer appears in Windows' "Apps & features", and if I run the installation file again it starts a new installation, as if the application had never been installed.

I tired enabling maintenance mode, but to no avail. Cancelling the maintenance dialog triggers the same partial removal.

Any clue what's going on here, or ideas to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced this issue when long back I was working on InstallShield scripting.

> The unexpected bit is that after closing this dialog, the application
>   is partially removed from my machine. The installed files and registry
>   keys are still present, but it no longer appears in Windows' "Apps &
>   features",

Have you implemented the uninstall script functions in your installscript for uninstalling or updating the installation? You may look into these functions and verify the logic for those particular features or components.

> and if I run the installation file again it starts a new installation,
>   as if the application had never been installed.

In the installer folder, where you have your installshield setup.exe, you have TEMP folder in that folder you have "Installation.ini" file, there it tracks the instances it has installed with that particular name. 
So it might be because installshield is removing the entry from installation.ini file and when you are trying to install the same package again you are able to do this.